# Change font of all texts in my Ionic APP

Tags: ionic2

Somebody know how can I change font of all texts (for example Dosis google font) in ionic 2?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

I did this in my ionic2 app with Quicksand google font:-

1. Download your favourite font
2. Add the regular font file from your downloaded zip to src/assets/font(adding a regular font gives you the flexibilty to play with font weights going ahead)
3. Then go to theme/variable.scss
4. Add the following code

```css
@font-face {
font-family: GlobalFont;
src: url("../assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf");
}

body, span, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ion-item, ion-title {
font-family: 'GlobalFont' !important;
}
```

then...

```
ionic serve
```

Voila..!!

Answer (score -3):

This topic was already discussed in the Ionic forum! https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-the-font-of-all-texts-in-ionic/30459

Comment: Yes, but is not for Ionic 2 :S