# Laravel Nova change font family

Tags: laravel-nova

Anyone knows how can i change the default **Nunito font** with the **Roboto Font** in Laravel Nova app?
I can not see anything in documentation
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change font of all texts in my Ionic APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175035/change-font-of-all-texts-in-my-ionic-app)

Comment: Sorry but not! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom css file to your nova app adding this in the boot method of your NovaServiceProvider.php

```
Nova::theme('link/to/your/file.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

follow me for some steps

1. create a `style.css` file in the `public` path example `public/css/style.css`
2. Booted `style.css` in `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php` in the `boot()` method.

Code:

```
use Laravel\Nova\Nova;

public function boot()
{
   parent::boot();
   Nova::style('style', public_path('css/style.css'));
}
```

3. Add code CSS in `style.css`

code example

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');


.font-sans {
    font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are possible 2 ways, that I know. First is to [create custom tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html#overview) and override `font-family`. This would load both default `Nunito` and `Roboto` fonts.

Another way, which I preferer is to override `layout.blade.php` file. Create `/resources/views/vendor/nova/layout.blade.php` file, and copy contents of original nova layout. Then you can change font as you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" class="h-full font-sans antialiased">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1280">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ \Laravel\Nova\Nova::name() }}</title>

    <!-- Change here to Roboto -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
```

This should be enough, but if not. Then add styles too, something like:

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

Keep in mind to update your layout, when upgrading nova